# Is it bad practice to create a new RunSpace from withing a custom C# cmdlet?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

Is it considered bad practice (or are there specific reasons not to) create a new RunSpace in a custom c# cmdlet?  For example, I have a custom Cmdlet, as below and need to call an existing cmdlet and I am wondering if there will be any threading or other issues with doing this.

```
 public class SPCmdletNewBusinessSite : SPNewCmdletBase<SPSite>
    {

...
     private void ExecuteRunspaceCommand()
            {
                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                PSSnapInException snapInError;
                runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out snapInError);
                runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.Default;
                runspace.Open();

                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

                Command newSiteProc = new Command("New-SPSite");
                newSiteProc.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Url", "http://goober-dc/9393"));
                newSiteProc.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("OwnerAlias", "GOOBER\\Administrator"));
                newSiteProc.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Template", "STS#1"));
                newSiteProc.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Language", "1033"));
                newSiteProc.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ContentDatabase", "Site_Specific_ContentDB"));

                pipeline.Commands.Add(newSiteProc);
                Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();

                results = pipeline.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    base.WriteObject(((SPSite)obj.BaseObject).RootWeb.Title);
                }                  

            }
}
```

Specifically, I want to create a SharePoint 2010 SPSite and specify a specific content database for the SPSite.  There is an overload for SPSitesCollection.Add() which accepts an SPContentDatabase as a parameter, but this is an internal method.  I want to create the RunSpace to enable calling the New-SPSite cmdlet (which allows specifying a new content db) and therefore be able to create the site with a specific content database.

I have found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714873(v=VS.85).aspx indicates you can invoke cmdlets from within cmdlets, but New-SPSite (actual class SPCmdletNewSite) is also internal and cannot be invoked directly.

Comment: It is not clear why you need an extra runspace. Unless you want to keep the current one free of the extra loaded snap-in, is that the reason? Is it the real code or pseudo code? In the latter case which part is pseudo? In particular, SPSitesCollection.Add() is mentioned but it is not used in the code (sorry if I just miss something).

Comment: Answering to the question in the title (I am not sure it is the actual question you are interested in), I do not think it is bad practice if there are reasons for creating new runspaces. Without reasons it is bad practice, new runspaces are not cheap.

Comment: Thanks Roman - I am trying to call the New-SPSite cmdlet whose actual class implemenation (in c#) is internal sealed,  "internal sealed class SPCmdletNewSite : SPNewCmdletBase<SPSite>".  Since I cannot call the Invoke on the cmdlet class directly, I am trying to find out what issues I might run into or be creating by calling the cmdlet in a separate RunSpace as described above.  If there are other alternatives, please let me know. I am relatively new to creating new custom cmdlets in c#.

Comment: Can you call this from PowerShell script, not smdlet? If yes, give us the code, it should be possible to call it from a cmdlet as well.

Comment: I can call New-SPSite from a script, and the code above works as well.   THis is not the problem.  My question is, since the cmdlet  SPCmdletNewSite  is marked "internal" and I cannot call the cmdlet's class from c# directly, is calling the cmdlet itself from another runspace a bad practice? will there be threading  or other issues?  Sorry if I am not clear, still learning...

Comment: Ah, well, then I think I answered by the second comment. The answer depends. BTW, in your code you do not call *cmdlet class* (low level), you still call it as a *command* `New-SPSite` (high level).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call another cmdlet inside a cmdlet, the usual practice is to use a nested *pipeline* not a new runspace. This lets you use the cmdlet's scope, giving you access to the same variables and context. A new runspace is completely isolated and is more heavyweight as a result but may be desired if you don't to polluate the calling scope. I think you probably want a nested pipeline so you don't have to reload the sharepoint snapin (I'm presuming it's already loaded when you call your new sharepoint cmdlet.)

You can use this method from within your cmdlet. It's a nested pipeline because your command is running in a pipeline already.

```
var pipe = Runspace.DefaultRunspace.CreateNestedPipeline(...);
pipe.Invoke()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.createnestedpipeline(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the info and for the link to further educate myself.